# Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)i.next();

Tags: java

Why do I need to have `(Map.Entry)` in front of the `i.next();` ? Why can't I have just `Map.Entry m = i.next();`?

Sorry. It is a HashMap.

Comment: Could you provide some context to this question? Unless i is explicitly defined as a list of type Map.Entry, you need to cast the next() result to Map.Entry

Comment: Kind of hard to answer the question if we don't know what "i" is.

Comment: Needs more context.  Can you post the whole method (or just the loop?)

Comment: Also what version of Java is it?

Answer (score 5):

Because it's apparently not an `Iterator<Map.Entry>`. Maybe it's an `Iterator<Object>`, or an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>>` or something different.

For example, the following `Map`

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

gives the following `Iterator` back

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

which in turn gives the following `Map.Entry` back on `next()`

```
Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
```

Comment: `Iterator<Map.Entry>` would be odd (or at least "rare"). Probably just an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

because you are not using the generics correctly (it's a hassle I know to type out everything over and over and over but it's worth it) they will do that (the casting to Map.Entry) for you when it all comes together

```
HashMap<String, YourClass> map;
Iterator<Map.entry<String, YourClass>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Map.entry<String, YourClass> entry = it.next();//see no explicit cast
    //use entry
}
```

as a final hint copy paste (and a decent IDE) is your greatest friend with generics

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a wild guess because you haven't posted any code or stated which version of Java you are using, but I am guessing that:

- You are used to Java (≥1.5) code that uses generics, e.g. `HashMap<K, V>`
- You are now maintaining a codebase written for Java 1.4 or earlier that does not use generics.

e.g. you may know that a `HashMap` has `String` keys and `Integer` values, but this cannot be reflected in the type of the `HashMap`, so you must cast individual values.

With generics:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map;

// ...

int sum = 0;
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
     it.hasNext;
     ) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();
    Integer value = e.getValue();
    sum += value.intValue();
}
```

Without generics:

```
HashMap map;

// ...

int sum = 0;
for (Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
     it.hasNext;
     ) {
    Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    Integer value = (Integer) e.getValue();
    sum += value.intValue();
}
```

If generics are unavailable (or you are working with a legacy library that gives you non-generic collections) you have no choice but to apply these casts.
BTW: Even if you *do* have generics, these casts are still applied under-the-hood by the compiler.

Note: leaving out foreach loops and auto-unboxing as these are also unavailable in Java 1.4 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Because `i.next()` returns object when you don't use generics and you have to cast it to be able to assign it.